How do I use nginx to access multiple php web applications in different subdirectories?
I have a Mediawiki and an Engelsystem instance currently running on different ports on my server but that is not how I would like to access them. I would like to access them via https://www.example.com/wiki and https://www.example.com/engelsystem respectively.
My Engelsystem config contains the following:
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name _;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key;

    root /var/www/html/engelsystem/public;

    index index.php;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

The Mediawiki config is almost an exact copy but with a different root and ports.
I tried to use aliases but this doesn't work for some reason. /wiki/ displays a 404 page and /engelsystem/ redirects to /engelsystem//public/. I'm new to nginx and I've got no idea why this isn't working. Any ideas?
Here's the config:
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name _;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key;

    root /var/www/html;

    index index.php;

    server_name _;

    location = / {
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html;
    }

    location /engelsystem/ {
        alias /var/www/html/engelsystem/public/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /engelsystem/index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location /wiki/ {
        alias /var/www/html/mediawiki/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /wiki/index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
    }

    # Deny access to .htaccess files
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}

error.log:

[error] 22663#22663: *219 open() "/var/www/html/favicon.ico" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.178.57, server: _, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.178.24", referrer: "https://192.168.178.24/wiki/"
[error] 22662#22662: *218 "/var/www/html/engelsystem/public/public/index.php" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 192.168.178.57, server: _, request: "GET /engelsystem//public/ HTTP/1.1", host: "192.168.178.24"

Obviously these locations are wrong, but why?

"The simplest solution is often the best"
Just use symlinks, get rid of nginx-specific configurations like
    location /engelsystem/ {
        alias /var/www/html/engelsystem/public/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /engelsystem/index.php?$query_string;
    }
    location /wiki/ {
        alias /var/www/html/mediawiki/;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /wiki/index.php?$query_string;
    }

(It would be possible to configure nginx and php-fpm to do what you want, but it is far easier to just use symlinks)
just keep it simple, something like
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php;
    server_name _;
    location = / {
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.3-fpm.sock;
    }

and run
ln -s /var/www/html/engelsystem /var/www/html/engelsystem/public/;
ln -s /var/www/html/wiki /var/www/html/mediawiki/;

now the endpoints /engelsystem and /wiki should work.

Obviously these locations are wrong, but why?

I haven't really tried figuring it out, but I believe it's a problem with how nginx sends alias paths to php-fpm.. it would be possible to fix, but if symlinks get the job done, it isn't worth the effort to figure out, IMO.
As a sidenote, I would advice moving engelsystem out of docroot, for security reasons. (visitors probably should not be allowed to browse the engelsystem files outside of the /public/ folder)

I've moved the Mediawiki and Engelsystem into a different directory (for consistency) and created symlinks. I can access both the wiki and the engelsystem however the content locations are still wrong which means the Mediawiki has no styling and no images and the Engelsystem isn't working at all.
Engelsystem: /var/www/html/favicon.ico
Mediawiki: /var/www/html/resources/assets/change-your-logo.svg, /var/www/html/resources/assets/licenses/gnu-fdl.png, /var/www/html/resources/assets/poweredby_mediawiki_88x31.png
